# Android: NFC Tag Technologies -> should they be checked and if yes how?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

My App is able to write to a NFC tag.

```
 ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
```

Should I check the supported NFC Tag technologies bevore writing to it, or will Android handle this problem by it´s own and throws an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will handle that for you. So normally you do not need to check it.

You may want to call `ndef.isWritable()` to check whether writing is possible and to be able to provide better feedback to the user.